# Caching API Data & Download Links

Tags: asp.net, caching, vimeo, vimeo-api

To reduce the number of API calls we're making on our website, I built in a cache using ASP.Net's caching library.

The cache is currently set for 30 minutes.

The problem we're running into is that the download links seem to expire before this or reach a maximum of some sort and users are getting a page that tells them they don't have access to the download.

Now, if I reset the cache, it works.

So I'm looking for help / advice on how to better handle this.

1) I could just not cache anything and make each page load an individual API call, but that seems like unnecessary overhead.

2) I could reduce the cache lifetime.

3) I could build a separate service on our end that goes around the cache when the user clicks to download.

I'm a fan of #2 and #3, but I wondered if someone else could help offer some suggestions.

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: I believe the download information also includes an expiration time. I believe the video links should be under download[$index].link and the expiration information under download[index].expires

Comment: Thanks, @Dashron. It does, but I can't figure out how to read it. I just ran the API call and this is the expiration value it put in the download link: 1462481254.

Comment: hmm. looks to be the absolute unix time that the link expires

Comment: Ah... Not familiar with that one, but Vimeo actually replied on their forums too and recommended using JSON filters to always grab a new download link, so that's what I'm going to do. Thanks again for your help!